# How to decrease the length of an integer Array (with binary data [0,1]) without losing data?

Tags: c#

I have an integer array of length 900 that contains only binary data [0,1].
I want to short the length of the array without losing binary data formate(original array values).

Is it possible to short the length of array of 900 into 10 or 20 length in C#???

Comment: What do you mean by "short the length". Do you mean [truncate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/truncate)?

Comment: I want to represent an array of 900 length to array or string of 10 or 20 length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually apply some compression on bits and then store it. if its only 1s and 0s, Run-length encoding may help reduce size drastically in not-worst scenarios.

[Run length encoding - Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

Comment: Good technique but not suitable with my scenario.

Answer (score 5):

Bitarray class will give you almost 1/32th of your int array's length.

Comment: That's not going to work... 900/32 is still a lot more than 10.

Comment: It's the best you can achieve in the general case. You can try to compress it, but that doesn't always help.

Comment: Its not good for my scenario. I have lots of arrays of 900 length and I have to save these values in database. If I save the original array or 1/32th, it increases the size of my database.Any other method???

Comment: @Henk: do you know any simple technique rather then Quantum theory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use System.Collections.BitArray

Here is the sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Collections.BitArray bits = new System.Collections.BitArray(900);

            // Setting all bits to 0
            bits.SetAll(false);

            // Here Im setting 21st bit in array
            bits[21] = true;
            // etc...

            int[] nativeBits = new int[29];

            // Packing your bits in int array
            bits.CopyTo(nativeBits, 0);

            // This prints 2097152. this is 2^21
            Console.WriteLine("First element is:"+nativeBits[0].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

nativeBits array consists of only 29 elements. And now you can convert it in string

Comment: To restore integer array into BitArray you can simply write `BitArray newBits = new BitArray(nativeBits);`

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you have a binary integer with 900 digits.  There are lots of ways you can hold that "number" depending on the what do you want with it and how fast.

Ask yourself:

- do I need fast set function ( `arr[n] = something` )
- do I need fast retrieval function ( val = arr[n] )
- do I need iteration of some kind, for example find next n for which arr[n] is 1

and so on.

Then, ask again or modify you original question.

Otherwise, `BitArray`

EDIT:

Since we found something (a little) I would suggest rolling your own class for that.

Class would have a container such as byte[] and methods to set and unset a item on some position.

Checking common 1s from two arrays would be as simple as &&-ing an array on byte to byte basis.

Comment: I have to save the multiple input array of 900 digits and then get back these array and compare with new coming arrays.

Comment: When comparing, what result do you want?

Comment: Results will be in probabilities.

Comment: What does that mean?  Total count of 1s?  ... ?

Comment: It gives the results of matching 0s and 1s in a specific pattern.